# Map the area $0<\theta<\pi$ with $w=\frac {-i}{\sqrt z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

how can I map the area $0<\theta<\pi$  with map-function
 $w=\frac {-i}{\sqrt z}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ($w$) is the successive transformation $z\to 1/z\to-z\to \sqrt{z}$. The fastest way to see how this affects the upper unit plane is to parametrize an open cover and look at the images of the end points. Because both $-z$ and $1/z$ are involved, it helps to break the domain into two open covers by avoiding the origin, the unit circle and the imaginary axis, by parametrizing as follows (to save space, the parametrization is included in the Maple code):

```
restart;
with(plots);
w := proc (z) options operator, arrow; -I/sqrt(z) end proc;
epsilon := .1;
z := proc (rho, theta) options operator, arrow; rho*exp(I*theta) end proc;
z1 := complexplot(z(1, theta), theta = 0+epsilon .. (1/2)*Pi-epsilon);
z2 := complexplot(z(epsilon, theta), theta = 0+epsilon .. (1/2)*Pi-epsilon);
z3 := complexplot(z(rho, (1/2)*Pi-epsilon), rho = epsilon .. 1);
z4 := complexplot(z(rho, epsilon), rho = epsilon .. 1);
qp1 := display(z1, z2, z3, z4, scaling = constrained);
z1 := complexplot(z(1, theta), theta = (1/2)*Pi+epsilon .. Pi-epsilon);
z2 := complexplot(z(epsilon, theta), theta = (1/2)*Pi+epsilon .. Pi-epsilon);
z3 := complexplot(z(rho, (1/2)*Pi+epsilon), rho = epsilon .. 1);
z4 := complexplot(z(rho, Pi-epsilon), rho = epsilon .. 1);
qp2 := display(z1, z2, z3, z4, scaling = constrained);
display(qp1, qp2);
```

[image]

and now you can see the image by calculating just the end points of the cover:

```
z1 := complexplot(w(z(1, theta)), theta = 0+epsilon .. (1/2)*Pi-epsilon, color = blue);
z2 := complexplot(w(z(epsilon, theta)), theta = 0+epsilon .. (1/2)*Pi-epsilon, color = blue);
z3 := complexplot(w(z(rho, (1/2)*Pi-epsilon)), rho = epsilon .. 1, color = blue);
z4 := complexplot(w(z(rho, epsilon)), rho = epsilon .. 1, color = blue);
iqp1 := display(z1, z2, z3, z4, scaling = constrained);
z1 := complexplot(w(z(1, theta)), theta = (1/2)*Pi+epsilon .. Pi-epsilon, color = blue);
z2 := complexplot(w(z(epsilon, theta)), theta = (1/2)*Pi+epsilon .. Pi-epsilon, color = blue);
z3 := complexplot(w(z(rho, (1/2)*Pi+epsilon)), rho = epsilon .. 1, color = blue);
z4 := complexplot(w(z(rho, Pi-epsilon)), rho = epsilon .. 1, color = blue);
iqp2 := display(z1, z2, z3, z4, scaling = constrained);
display(iqp1, iqp2);
```

[image]